# python, repeat random.randint?

Tags: python

I am new to python and i would like to know how to make the code to repeat the `random.randint` part 100 times.

```
#head's or tail's

print("you filp a coin it lands on...")

import random

heads = 0
tails = 0


head_tail =random.randint(1, 2,)

if head_tail == 1:
    print("\nThe coin landed on heads")
else:
    print("\nThe coin landed on tails")

if head_tail == 1:
    heads += 1
else:
   tails += 1

flip = 0
while True :
    flip +=1
    if flip > 100:
        break



print("""\nThe coin has been fliped 100 times
it landed on heads""", heads, """times and tails""", tails,
"""times""")

input("Press the enter key to exit")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it all in one line with a list comprehension:

```
flips = [random.randint(1, 2) for i in range(100)]
```

And count the number of heads/tails like this:

```
heads = flips.count(1)
tails = flips.count(2)
```

Or better yet:

```
num_flips = 100
flips = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in xrange(num_flips)]
heads = sum(flips)
tails = num_flips - heads
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would replace that `while` loop with:

```
for flip in xrange(100):
  ...
```

Secondly, to conduct 100 random trials, move the `randint()` call -- as well as everything else that you want to perform 100 times -- inside the body of the loop:

```
for flip in xrange(100):
  head_tail = random.randint(1, 2)
  ...
```

Finally, here is how *I* would do the whole thing:

```
heads = sum(random.randint(0, 1) for flip in xrange(100))
tails = 100 - heads
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use `range(100)`, since you're on Python3.x which creates a list from 0 to 99 (100 items). It'll look something like this:

```
print("you flip a coin it lands on...")

import random

heads = 0
tails = 0


for i in xrange(100):
    head_tail = random.randint((1, 2))

    if head_tail == 1:
        print("\nThe coin landed on heads")
    else:
        print("\nThe coin landed on tails")

    if head_tail == 1:
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1    


print("""\nThe coin has been fliped 100 times
it landed on heads""", heads, """times and tails""", tails,
"""times""")

input("Press the enter key to exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for flip in range(100):
    head_tail = random.randint(1, 2)

    if head_tail == 1:
        print("\nThe coin landed on heads")
    else:
        print("\nThe coin landed on tails")

    if head_tail == 1:
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in Python and generally in programming, but I created my own code base on 1 day programming practice. Coin flip coding exercise is one of the first from the book I study now. I tried to find solution on the internet and I found this topic.

I was aware to use any code from this topic because few functions used in previous answers were not familiar to me.

To anyone in similar situation: Please feel free to use my code.

```
import random

attempts_no = 0
heads = 0
tails = 0

input("Tap any key to flip the coin 100 times")


while attempts_no != 100:
 number = random.randint(1, 2)
 attempts_no +=1
 print(number)
 if number == 1:
    heads +=1
 elif number ==2:
    tails +=1

print("The coin landed on heads", heads, "times")
print("The coin landed on heads", tails, "times")
```